# unable to parse json using jquery after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

this is my php script

```
<?php

$wishes_array["wishes_text"] = null;
$wishes_array["total"] = null;
$count = 0;
// wishes has all records
if(!is_null($wishes))
{
    foreach($wishes as $wish)
    {
        if($wish->text != null)
        {
             $wishes_array["wishes_text"][$count] = html_escape($wish->text);
             $count++;
        }
     }
     $wishes_array["total"] = sizeof($wishes);
     echo json_encode($wishes_array);
}
?>
```

**background**

a user sends his wishes using a button, but he has an option to send some message with his wish, suppose person A just sent wish, but person B sent wish with text "happy birthday", person C sent wish with text "have a great birthday"

now using this array we have array which tells `total` number of wishes recieved(with and without wish text) and `wishes` the text of the wishes sent by person.

**problem**

unable to use parse the json using jquery, here is what i've done and it return `undefined`

```
var total_start = '<div style="padding: 3px;margin: 10px auto;"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="background: #e53935; color: #fff;padding: 5px;border-radius: 50%;"></i> ';
var total_end = '</div>';
var startString = '<div style="padding: 3px;margin: 10px auto;"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="background: #e53935; color: #fff;padding: 5px;border-radius: 50%;"></i>';
var endSting = '</div>';
var wishes = '';
var count = 0;
if(data["wishes_text"] != null){
     $.each(data, function(index, element) {
         wishes += startString;
         wishes += ' ' + data["wishes_text"][count];
         wishes += endSting;
         count++;
     });
 }
 var total = "";
 if(data["total"] == 1)
 {
     total = total_start + data["total"] + ' person wished' + total_end;
 }
 else
 {
     total = total_start + data["total"] + ' people wished' + total_end;
 }
 $('#wish_div').html(total + wishes);
```

**ajax response json**

`{"wishes_text":["wish 1","wish 2"],"total":3}`

Comment: Where's your code that makes the AJAX request? It would also help to see the actual JSON response, not the PHP that generates it

Comment: Look at the `data` variable using the browsers debugger. I bet its an object and not an array, because `json_encode()` will create an JSON object if the array you use is not numerically indexed, as javascript arrays have to be numerically indexed

Comment: Need to show us where you run that javscript. Also what exactly is undefined?

Comment: @charlietfl updated the question

Comment: @RiggsFolly updated the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan updated the question

Comment: For starters you want `$.each(data["wishes_text"]` and inside that `element` will be each array value

Comment: Yup, told you so thats a JSON String defining an object

Comment: @runningmark thanks, I added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is simply that you're attempting to iterate through `data` instead of the `wishes_text` array contained within `data`. Note that you can also tidy up the logic slightly. Try this:

```
var total = '<div style="padding: 3px;margin: 10px auto;"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="background: #e53935; color: #fff;padding: 5px;border-radius: 50%;"></i>' + data["total"] + ' ' + (data.total == 1 ? 'person' : 'people') + ' wished</div>';
var startString = '<div style="padding: 3px;margin: 10px auto;"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="background: #e53935; color: #fff;padding: 5px;border-radius: 50%;"></i>';
var endSting = '</div>';
var wishes = '';

if (data.wishes_text != null) {
    $.each(data.wishes_text, function(index, element) {
        wishes += startString + ' ' + data["wishes_text"][index] + endSting;
    });
}
$('#wish_div').html(total + wishes);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/me0L1069/)

I'd also suggest you look in to using stylesheets and classes over inline styling, and also a templating library as the large chunks of HTML in the JS code are on the limit of being 'too big', from a best practice point of view.